# Куда сохраняется состояние Radiobutton?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
var=IntVar()
rb1=Radiobutton(root,text='50',variable=var,value=1)
rb2=Radiobutton(root,text='100',variable=var,value=2)
rb3=Radiobutton(root,text='200',variable=var,value=3)
rb4=Radiobutton(root,text='500',variable=var,value=4)
rb1.place(x=150, y=125)
rb2.place(x=200, y=125)
rb3.place(x=150, y=150)
rb4.place(x=200, y=150)
```

Возьмем часть кода, которая создает 4 кнопки с выбором одной из них. Допустим пользователь нажал на `rb2` в окне. Как я понял данные должны сохранится в переменную `value`, но после попытки вывести это на экран, я получил ошибку. В какую переменную сохранились данные о том, что выбор пользователя `rb2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно создать события обработки действия нажатия на кнопку. Можно 2 способами либо создать кнопку `Button` и назначить на нее вызов функции `check`  как в примере и при помощи `var.get()` получить значение  значение `value` из `Radiobutton`

```
from tkinter import *


def check():
    radio_button = var.get()
    print(radio_button)


root = Tk()
var = IntVar()
rb1 = Radiobutton(root,text='50',variable=var,value=1)
rb2 = Radiobutton(root,text='100',variable=var,value=2)
rb3 = Radiobutton(root,text='200',variable=var,value=3)
rb4 = Radiobutton(root,text='500',variable=var,value=4)
rb1.place(x=50, y=125)
rb2.place(x=100, y=125)
rb3.place(x=50, y=150)
rb4.place(x=100, y=150)
button = Button(root, text='получение значение радиокнопки', command=check)
button.place(x=0, y=0)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Либо назначить команду на каждую `Radiobutton` и после таким же методом получать значение

```
from tkinter import *


def check():
    radio_button = var.get()
    print(radio_button)


root = Tk()
var = IntVar()
rb1 = Radiobutton(root, text='50', variable=var, value=1, command=check)
rb2 = Radiobutton(root, text='100', variable=var, value=2, command=check)
rb3 = Radiobutton(root, text='200', variable=var, value=3, command=check)
rb4 = Radiobutton(root, text='500', variable=var, value=4, command=check)
rb1.place(x=50, y=125)
rb2.place(x=100, y=125)
rb3.place(x=50, y=150)
rb4.place(x=100, y=150)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

> Как я понял данные должны сохранится в переменную `value`

На самом деле данные сохраняются в переменную `var` (переменной `value` в коде нету, это именованный параметр конструктора). Получить текущее значение `RadioButton` можно вызвав метод `get()` у переменной `var`:

```
var = IntVar()
button1 = Radiobutton(root, text='sometext', variable=var, value=1)
...
print(var.get())  # получаем состояние радиокнопок
```